# where are codiad projects stored locally?

Tags: scripting, browser, ruby, development, ide

In Firefox I installed [codiad](https://github.com/Codiad/Codiad/wiki/Quick-install-on-Ubuntu) as:

[image: codiad]

where is `ruby_hello` actually located?

(When it asked for the absolute path, I wasn't able to put in `/home/thufir/...` because of permission, so just typed in "codiad" with no path...but where is "codiad" actually located?)

Answer (score 0):

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ ll /var/www/html/workspace/codiad/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 28 20:22 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Oct 28 20:15 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   12 Oct 28 20:22 foo.rb
thufir@doge:~$
```

https://github.com/Codiad/Codiad/wiki/Pathing-&-The-Workspace